# Get http 403 error substatus

Tags: java, http

I am trying to download a file on http in java code. I keep getting Exception 403 and I am not sure exactly the specific reason. According to [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) there must be a way to get exact substatus error.

Any way we can get substatus error in Java please so that I can fix it accordingly?

```
private void downloadFile()
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://hostname/folder/fileName");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
        int length = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((length = in.read(data)) != -1)
        {
            System.out.write(data);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

java.io.IOException: 
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://hostname/folder/fileName
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `According to Wikipedia article there must be a way to get exact substatus error` where have you read that? according to the article, I understand that the server may chose to return a more specific code (instead of just 403), but it is not forced to do so. Anyway I would try with `HttpUrlConnection` to try to access the raw header info.

Comment: Since wikipedia mentioned that there will be substatus returned I assumed there must be an api in Java to get that. I am not 100% sure though.

Comment: 1. No, there's not. 2. It's only for IIS anyway.

Comment: Just to double check ... you are actually substituting the correct hostname and path and filename into the URL connection because the error references http://hostname/folder/fileName which does not look like a valid well named URL?

Comment: Also try inputting the URL directly into a browser and see what happens? Do you get the same error as when you run the app? Double check that the file is actually there and if the file is there double check access/read permissions